# What kind of primitive data is this?

Tags: java

In java, something like,

```
1.3418043127890081341
```

?

I get really confused with double floats and long.

Can someone help me to remember it better?

Comment: Er, what's the question? I'm not sure I quite get it...

Comment: what kind of primitive data is the number, is it float?

Comment: This is a `double`.  Basically, if there's no letter suffix (like L or F) then a number literal is `int` if there's no decimal point, or `double` if there is a decimal point.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about A mnemonic for remembering what is a float vs. double. vs. decimal vs. dinosaur.

Comment: Integers are integers while decimal numbers are double. A simple google search confirms this. I personally always add `D` and `F` when using a primitive `double` or `float`, it helps readability.

Comment: *"Can someone help me to remember it better?"* - I recommend that you get a piece of 4-by-2 timber.  Each time you get it wrong, WHACK yourself on the head with your 4-by-2.  You'll soon learn to get it right.  :-)  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be stored as a `float` (single precision) or `double` (double precision). Both are used to store numbers with decimal point.

It cannot be stored as a `long` because `long` is used to store integers. In other words, it's like a "bigger" `int`. One way to remember it is as *"a long integer"*.

Notice that if you want to store it as a `float` you should add the postfix `f` or `F`:

```
float f = 1.3418043127890081341f;
double d = 1.3418043127890081341;
```

Answer (score 2):

Any number containing a decimal point in it is considered a [Floating Point Literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) by Java.

Because in your case, you did not suffix it with the letter 'f' or 'F', Java considers this floating point literal to be of the primitive type `double`. See the [Java Language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2):

> A floating-point literal is of type `float` if it is suffixed with an
>   ASCII letter F or f; otherwise its type is `double` and it can
>   optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter D or d (§4.2.3).